# Drupal Hook for taxonomy weight change

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-hooks

Is there any hook or way to execute a code when we change the taxonomy terms weight. E.g When we change create parent/child relationship between the terms.
**function hook_taxonomy_term_update** Doesn't seem to work for that.

Comment: Here is a suggested workaround: https://api.drupal.org/comment/49833#comment-49833

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the Answer. I too found this and have already implemented the same.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the answer to this when i found the solution

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'taxonomy_overview_terms':

          if($form['#vocabulary']->machine_name == 'your_vocabulary_name'){
            //adding a custom callback for after re-ordering
            $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_custom_callback';
          }

        break;
    }
}

function mymodule_custom_callback(){
    //custom logic
}
```